# Problem dismissing an ABUnknownPersonViewController. Shows up fine but app crashes when dismissing

Tags: iphone, objective-c, addressbook

My app is consisted of 2 views. The MainView and ResultsView. MainView contains a UITextField that needs to be filled and then if a button is touched, the view changes to ResultsView. Below is the juicy part of the code that handles that.

```
// In CallerIDAppDelegate.h
@class MainViewController;
@class ResultsViewController;

@interface CallerIDAppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate> {
    UIWindow *window;

    IBOutlet MainViewController *mainViewController;
    IBOutlet ResultsViewController *resultsViewController;

    NSString *phoneNumber;

   NSMutableArray *parsingResults;

   BOOL isSearchingForSaved;
}
[...]

// In CallerIDAppDelegate.m
[...]
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application {
    /* Set up and display MainView */
    MainViewController *mainController = [[MainViewController alloc]    initWithNibName:@"MainView" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    self.mainViewController = mainController;
    [window addSubview:mainController.view];

    // Override point for customization after application launch
    [window makeKeyAndVisible];
}

-(void)switchViews{
    if(self.resultsViewController == nil){
        ResultsViewController *resultsController = [[ResultsViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ResultsViewController" bundle:nil];
        self.resultsViewController = resultsController;
        [resultsController release];
    }

    if(self.mainViewController.view.superview == nil){
        [resultsViewController.view removeFromSuperview];
        [window insertSubview:mainViewController.view atIndex:0];
    } else {
        [mainViewController.view removeFromSuperview];
        [window insertSubview:resultsViewController.view atIndex:0];
    }
}
```

Now in `ResultsView` I have a tableview with some content. What I want to do is, when a row from that tableview is selected, I want to invoke the `ABUnknownPersonViewController` so the user can save a contact to the addressbook.

So in `ResultsViewController.m`:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    [...]
    ABUnknownPersonViewController *unknownPersonView = [[[ABUnknownPersonViewController alloc] init] autorelease];

    [unknownPersonView setUnknownPersonViewDelegate:self];

    [unknownPersonView setDisplayedPerson:personRecord];
    [unknownPersonView setAllowsAddingToAddressBook:YES];

    UINavigationController *navigationController = [[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:unknownPersonView] autorelease];


    [self presentModalViewController:navigationController animated:YES];
}

- (void)unknownPersonViewController:(ABUnknownPersonViewController *)unknownPersonView didResolveToPerson:(ABRecordRef)person {
    CallerIDAppDelegate *delegate = (CallerIDAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    DLog("Called!");
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES]; //caused crash

    // Caused crash too
    //[delegate.resultsViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimate:YES]; 
}
```

The `ABUnknownPersonViewController` is displayed properly when the row is selected. It also contains all the correct info that was sent through `personRecord` and saves the contact properly in addressbook when the "Add to Contacts" button is pressed. BUT, when the done (or cancel) button is pressed in the last step, it crashes pretty BAD!

The problem is, I can't understand anything from debugger, since, when launched, it says, "Loading 43453 stack frames…," which procedure I stop. The top of the stack trace is:

```
[CALayer sublayers];
```

and then there are *a LOT* of

```
[UIView(Hierarchy) _makeSubtreePerformSelector:withObject:withObject:copySublayers:]
```

Please enlighten me. I am sure its probably a little stupid thing that I'm doing wrong. I've been trying for hours to fix that, but I can't. :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fix it..... it was indeed stupid.

It should be:

```
- (void)unknownPersonViewController:(ABUnknownPersonViewController *)unknownPersonView didResolveToPerson:(ABRecordRef)person {
CallerIDAppDelegate *delegate = (CallerIDAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
DLog("Called!");
[unknownPersonView dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

}

Comment: The solutions you learn the most from are the ones you find yourself.  Welcome to Stack Overflow :)